# How to use chained exceptions

Tags: java, exception

In my application I have never used chained exception. But I am really looking forward to use it as I believe it can make my code better. But being new to it can someone provide me with some example as in what type of scenario and how can it be used?

Comment: Not really clear but what you mean by chained exception, where did you come across the concept?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020876/what-is-the-advantage-of-chained-exceptions

Answer (score 3):

[From docs directly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html)

The following example shows how to use a chained exception.

```
try {

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new SampleException("Other IOException", e);
}
```

In this example, when an `IOException` is caught, a new `SampleException` exception is created with the original `cause` attached and the chain of `exceptions` is thrown up to the next higher level `exception` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  try{
       .....
     }catch(ArithmeticExecption e){
                                      ....
                                  }
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .// u can add various exceptions like this
      catch(Exception e){
                          ....
                        }
```

//And if you are not sure which exception to use , use the more
general exception ,like i mentioned above